# How to manually reproduce any pending maintenance actions in Aurora PostgreSQL DBClusters on AWS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I wanted to reproduce Maintenance actions to check the changes I have made in my code.
I tried few things but am unable to do it, here are some of them:

1. Tried to Manually downgrade the AuroraDB engine version and then
   upgrade it to higher versions. Did it by manually modifying the
   DBCluster engine version on AWS console.
2. I tried to change the Maintenance window on AWS console as well to come up with any
   pending maintenance action.
3. Tried to change the AuroraDB engine version in auroraconfig.yaml and coming up with a
   DB cluster for the specified version.

Can someone please suggest me how to come up with any pending maintenance actions?

Comment: What type of maintenance action was it? If you just need any type, you can generate a pending maintenance action by changing a parameter in the DB options group that requires a restart. RDS won't apply this until a maintenance window or you do a restart, whichever is first.

Comment: Can you please specify some such Parameters, I was not able to find any. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm sorry I said Option group and I meant Parameter group. This page has a list for PostgresSQL. Any option marked `Static` needs a restart to take effect which will manifest as a pending change that would be done in the maintenance window: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Parameters.html

Comment: The DBCluster I am using uses default.aurora-postgresql10 as the DBClusterParameterGroup which when modified gives an error saying: 

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the ModifyDBClusterParameterGroup operation: Cannot modify a default parameter group.

Can you please tell me what to do with this error?

Comment: Sure, you can create a new parameter group and assign it to your DB.

Comment: I tried changing static parameters by creating a new parameter group and assigning to it, still nothing came up on the maintenance list.

It didn't ask to reboot as well.